# Evening sky, or how do I use the Sky Texture Node?

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to create a sky and light setup to approximate this image:

[image: Blue Hour]

Something like what photographers call the blue hour. Apart from the orange spot lights there is the gradient created by the indirect light from the sun that is sitting below the horizon. I have made this super quick setup to begin approximating it:

[image]

Why does the ColorRamp not work as it should? With four colour stops I should see a gradient no? With the orange on the horizon. You can see the sunlamp is pointing directly up, so the light on the sphere is coming from below.

Maybe there is something I'm not understanding about how to employ the Sky Texture. Can it be tied to the sunlamp in some way?

The light from the sky should affect objects in the scene as well as the spot lamps. So how would you recreate the sky and lights for a scene like the image? Sincere thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about *Sky Texture* but it looks like this setup works the way you want:

Plug the *Sky Texture* (*Preetham* mode) into a *Gradient* into your *ColorRamp* (always better to use a *Gradient* before a *ColorRamp* if you want your gradient to look like your *ColorRamp* spectrum, I dont know why though).

You can also use *Texture Coordinate* > *Mapping* nodes before your Sky Texture if you want more control on the sky position/orientation.

[image]

Comment: Cheers @moonboots, that is helpful. After your advice and a lot of tweaking, I ended up using just a gradient texture and color ramp on a seamless backdrop style object to simulate the atmosphere I was after. Sort of works. I couldn't get the Sky Texture to work satisfactorily. Is the Sky Texture node outdated? I can't find much documentation of it? Even the Blender manual is a little bare bones on the subject, I guess it's straightforward enough though. But how would you achieve a sort of procedural sundown effect like this? HDRi maps? Cheers for your tireless efforts Moonbots: the Legend.

Comment: I guess Sky Texture is useful to quickly set a background gradient. About your sunset, it depends on a lot of thing: Are you planning to animate it? Do you want to make a 360° view? Is your style realistic or cartoonish? etc... You could also simply use a photo or paint on a surface (I personally like this solution)

Comment: Yea that sounds about right, Sky Texture seems to need a lot of tweaking and additional inputs to approach anything like realism. In my case just the individual render, approaching realism, but not photo realism. Maybe just relying on photos is the way forward, or surfaces as I have been using seamless backdrops to some effect. Thanks again

Comment: yes you can paint your sky on a surface, or bent surface, or semi-spherical background, use large and blurry brushes in photoshop